# how to replace whole route with javascript in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have nested routing in my angular apliccation. My routing in app module look's like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(
        (m) => m.DashboardModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'auth',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and nested routes in auth module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterPageComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}
```

When i am on login page route is: /auth/login
And after log in succees i try to change route to /dashboard with this code:

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']
```

but instead of it i am redirected to /dashboard/login. How can i get rid of this /login ?

Comment: In your dashboard somewhere you are redirecting ?

Comment: Do you have some Route Guard in use?

Comment: So it was late, i was tired and didn't notice that i was just simply redirecting in dashboard module. Thank you.